# Pdf indexing and searching in solr search with php

Tags: php, pdf, solr, upload

I have been searching all over the internet about how to index and search pdf files in solr search with php. I have setup apache solr on my local machine but not able to figure out how to index my pdf content and search for pdf filename.

What I actually want is whenever a user uploads a pdf through php file upload module the uploaded file gets indexed on solr server and when user searches for a text in php module it fetches the file name.

Comment: pdf != txt............

Comment: @smith sry didn't get that

Comment: pdf is not a text format, you seem to want to treat it as one

Comment: How are you accessing Solr? With a library? curl?

Comment: @MatsLindh php curl

Comment: @MatshLindh I tried and was able to post file to solr in php curl. Also, able to index and search content.

Comment: So then what's the question?

Comment: @MatsLindh The question was regarding solr search in php. But i've figured in out thanks.